# where i put my needed jar files in ofbiz-trunk folder?

Tags: ofbiz

i want to put my necessary jar files in my ofbiz-trunk folder.but i don't know where i place the jar files.please tell me the location...

Bye,

Saravanan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try putting them under framework/webapp/lib and see if the classes get loaded successfully at runtime

[This URL](http://ritesht.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-ofbiz-and-wicket-part-i.html) has an example of adding 3rd party jars into OFBiz under hot-deploy/myapp/webapp/myapp/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: jose can u tell me one thing, if i put the location u said,then how to import those file in my java class... import org.ofbiz.then the jar file class ,right...

Comment: the order of import does not matter. if the class is not found, it will crib anyway.

Comment: Hi Jose, i put the jar files(poi-3.6) in the path u said, both framework/webapp/lib and also hot-deploy/myapp/webapp/myapp/WEB-INF/lib.but when building ofbiz it says package does not exist.... please guide me to get correct way...

Answer (score 0):

We have been using Ofbiz for a while and have always placed 3rd party JARs in famework/base/lib folder and these JARs become available to all the applications/components in Ofbiz.